# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Ah!  I saw the review count jump into double digits and was *wondering* what had happened -- did somebody who can't directly edit go on an editing spree?  Then I saw the new queue. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What are some strategies for surprising the reader?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/what-are-some-strategies-for-surprising-the-reader)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to deal with two ISBN from two different countries?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/how-to-deal-with-two-isbn-from-two-different-countries)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Do published authors have rights to use their own book cover images?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12298/do-published-authors-have-rights-to-use-their-own-book-cover-images)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there a standard for what should be included in an index?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/is-there-a-standard-for-what-should-be-included-in-an-index)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [A novel without verbs?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/a-novel-without-verbs)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Does it confuse readers if a character name is similar to the name of an object?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12399/does-it-confuse-readers-if-a-character-name-is-similar-to-the-name-of-an-object)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Inserting truthful (derogatory) statements in text](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/inserting-truthful-derogatory-statements-in-text)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Tactician's Viewpoint and Contradictory Characterization](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/tacticians-viewpoint-and-contradictory-characterization)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Sluglines for same location but different periods, real and imagined](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12379/sluglines-for-same-location-but-different-periods-real-and-imagined)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is this title suitable for a chapter section?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12286/is-this-title-suitable-for-a-chapter-section)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Comment: "A novel without verbs": (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5).  That's extreme.